# Rails 4 - has_and_belongs_to_many assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I created a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) association between users and projects so that a user would be able to join in on a project. The association table exists however, I am unsure how I would create the association.

[**View**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgVfp.png)

[**Schema**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncq18.png)

Comment: The question here is how to write code to assing user to a project with has and belongs to many association?

Comment: yes! Im not sure where to start T_T

Answer (score 1):

I definitely must recommend you to **not** use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, because there is no way for you do to callbacks, validations and so on.

It is definitely nice to use a real join model and use `has_many, through`.

```
class User
  has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

class Project
  has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end

class ProjectUser
  belongs_to :project, required: true
  belongs_to :user, required: true

  validates :project, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
end
```

This works very seamlessly, you can do:

```
User.update(project_ids: [1,5,6,7])
```

And it will join the user to these project unless any validations fail.

I started out a big project with these tables everywhere, after a few months we started running into duplication issues, bad state of records and it was a hot mess. Using a real join model is so worth it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Ill be sure to keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your project ID inside hidden you could just do this inside JOIN (post) action

```
def join
  @project = Project.find(params[:project][:id])
  current_user.projects << @project
end
```

so if you have instance of @project and instance of user - in my example it is current_user( for example if you use devise) then you would just assign them using operator <<

Here is the reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for responding. How would i then display the users that clicked join into the group?